# Bokeh and Networkx - Hover tooltip showing multiple arrows

Tags: python, matplotlib, tooltip, bokeh, networkx

I've been playing around with visualising a networkx network in bokeh, using the following code...

```
import networkx as nx
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from bokeh.plotting import figure, ColumnDataSource
from bokeh.models.sources import CDSView
from bokeh.io import show, output_notebook
from bokeh.models import Plot, Range1d, MultiLine, Circle, HoverTool, BoxZoomTool, ResetTool
from bokeh.models.graphs import from_networkx, NodesAndLinkedEdges, EdgesAndLinkedNodes, NodesOnly
from bokeh.palettes import *

V = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
E = [(1,2), (4,5), (2,3)]

G=nx.Graph()
G.add_nodes_from(V)
G.add_edges_from(E)

plot = figure(plot_width=500, plot_height=500,
            x_range=Range1d(-1.1, 1.1), y_range=Range1d(-1.1, 1.1))
plot.title.text = "Networkx/Bokeh Example"
plot.axis.visible = None
plot.background_fill_color = "white"
plot.grid.grid_line_color = None

network_src = dict()
network_src['index'] = V
network_src['name'] = ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five', 'six']
network_src['size'] = [15,15,15,30,15,30]
network_src['node_cols'] = ['#2b83ba','#2b83ba','#2b83ba','#abdda4','#abdda4','#fdae61']
network_src = ColumnDataSource(network_src)

graph_renderer = from_networkx(G, nx.spring_layout, scale=1, center=(0, 0))
graph_renderer.node_renderer.glyph = Circle(size='size', fill_color='node_cols')
graph_renderer.node_renderer.data_source = network_src
graph_renderer.node_renderer.view = CDSView(source=network_src)

node_hover_tool = HoverTool(tooltips=[("Name", "@name")])

plot.add_tools(node_hover_tool)

plot.renderers.append(graph_renderer)

output_notebook()
show(plot)
```

This works fine, but when I hover over some of the nodes it shows more than one arrow around the box. I've read that this is because it's trying to assign the hover tooltip to both the edges and the node renderers... but I've tried to fix it and can't seem to find the right solution. Please help! Thanks.

Comment: I thought putting 'renderers = [graph_renderer.node_renderer]' in HoverTool() would fix it, but then I just ended up with no hovertool boxes at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like a bug. Please report it [here](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/issues). For now you could use:

```
node_hover_tool = HoverTool(tooltips = [("Name", "@name")], show_arrow = False)
```